# SQL Server uses db_owner prefix in selects on client's database

Tags: python, sql-server, django, odbc

My Django app is normally working on SQLite3, but this time I had to convert it to use SQL Server. On test server everything went well, but when my friend copied this database to client's server I had an error:

```
(norm)esd@server:~/Desktop/norm/myproject> python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fc57eb4f8c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 163, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 176, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 66, in applied_migrations
    return set(tuple(x) for x in self.migration_qs.values_list("app", "name"))
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 128, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 802, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 537, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_migrations'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

It's an error showing up when I'm trying to migrate, runserver etc etc.

I discovered that when I'm logged in database directly from Linux (sqlcmd), I can't do "normal" selects too, like

```
SELECT * FROM django_migrations;
```

Today I discovered that I can use it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM db_owner.django_migrations;
```

And it would be end of my problems, but how can I tell Django Models to use it this way or fix up db? On test database (Other server, the same SQL Serverversion etc) everything works very well. When I'm trying to do select from tables WITHOUT db_owner prefix, this error shows up:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_migrations'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Comment: can you show your `DATABASE` settings from settings.py?

Comment: This is called `schema` in MSSQL, not "prefix". My guess is that you've used `db_owner` login/user (which is a bad login name choice) while _converting_ from SQLite to MSSQL and the user was created without `WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=...` option, thus it has default schema = `db_owner` and all the objects created under this login are created in his default schema if object schema is not explicitly defined. If I'm not mistaken, Django knows nothing about any db _schemas_ (pg, ms), so creation scripts are generated without explicitly defined schema.

Comment: Currently you are using different user which has it's own `DEFAULT_SCHEMA` or `dbo` and thus cannot access those tables. So the problem started at the conversion time. Currently you can fix user/login definitions on DB server side and alter all the object names manually - set their schema as `dbo`.

Answer (score 0):

As Ivan said, I altered all tables to use dbo schema instead of db_owner and everything started working! I did

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER db_owner.tableName;
```

On every table in my db.